# Dynamixel MX-106T (2.0) Profile Velocity and Profile Acceleration using U2D2 and Wizard 2.0

Tags: software, dynamixel

I am trying to control the MX-106 servo by setting the Profile Velocity and Profile Acceleration under [Current-based Position Control Mode](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/dxl/mx/mx-106-2/#operating-mode11) using the Wizard software. However, I am not getting the trapezoidal velocity in the graph.

In [e-Manual](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/dxl/mx/mx-106-2/#indirect-address) of MX-106R, MX-106T (Protocol 2.0) it is described as Profiles are usually selected by the combination of Profile Velocity(112) and Profile Acceleration(108).

Following [Profile](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/dxl/mx/mx-106-2/#what-is-the-profile) details;

[image]

That means, to get the trapezoidal Profile, [Profile Velocity(112)](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/dxl/mx/mx-106-2/#profile-velocity112) and [Profile Acceleration(108)](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/dxl/mx/mx-106-2/#profile-acceleration108) shouldn’t be equal to zero. Here I tried with random values however it seems none of them worked.

Therefore, what values should I set for the Profile Acceleration? to make it not equal to zero to get the trapezoidal Profile.

[image]

And, by checking the graph with these values, it shows;

[image]

Actually, it is showing the rectangular Profile which may be because of the Profile Acceleration value is not right. Can someone guide me how I can get the trapezoidal Profile to control the MX servo using [U2D2](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/parts/interface/u2d2/) hardware with [Wizard](https://emanual.robotis.com/docs/en/software/dynamixel/dynamixel_wizard2/) software?